# Way to set OAuth Token on TTUrlRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, oauth, three20

I'm implementing OAuth in my app using gtm-oauth or oauthconsumer (haven't decided yet which one is easier).

The thing is, for my server api calls I'm using TTUrlRequest, is there any easy way to associate the access token with a TTUrlRequest like there is with NSMutableURLRequest ?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used OAuth -- if you were using `NSMutableURLRequest`, how would the access token get passed?  Via a URL parameter?  Some data in a POST body?  A cookie?  An HTTP header?

Comment: I Guess within the Header or Body of the html... I just hoped there is an easier way for me to use this than appending all this info now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [OAuthConsumer](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/), and setting the header manually.